# jQuery passing arguments fails - works without passing arguments

Tags: jquery

I cannot get this jQuery function to work with passing the div id as an argument rather than typing the div id inside the actual script (if I did it that way then I would need a script for every div). Any ideas why this isn't working? I'm relatively new to jQuery. The debugger says 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: home'

Hovering over the blue div should apply another css style class and turn the div red.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

```js
function hoverOverWindows(div) {
    var id = "#" + div;
    $('id').addClass('hover-over-windows-style');
};

function hoverAwayFromWindows(div) {
    var id = "#" + div;
    $('#div').removeClass('hover-over-windows-style');
};
```

```css
.home-match-type {
    width: 47%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.home-match-type-left { margin-right: 3% }


.img-text-container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
    background: rgba(60, 122, 173, 0.95);
}

.img-text-container-type-2 { background: rgba(60, 122, 173, 0.95) }

.img-text {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

h3.img-text.img-header { float: left }

h3.img-text.img-header.be-central { float: none }

.img-header {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(213, 213, 213, 0.3);
}

.hover-over-windows-style {
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="assets/css/lib/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<article class="home-match-type home-match-type-left">
            <div class="img-text-container img-text-container-type-2" id="home-m-t-1" onmouseover="hoverOverWindows(home-m-t-1)" onmouseout="hoverAwayFromWindows(home-m-t-1)">
                <h3 class="img-text img-header be-central windows-type-2"><a href="matches/blitz.html">Some Text</a></h3>
                <p class="img-text text-align-centre windows-type-2">lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer </p>
            </div>
        </article>
```

Comment: You mind including the part of your JavaScript where you are using the variable 'home'? I want to see what you are assigning to 'home' and what that variable is doing.

Comment: `$('id')` should be `$(id)`. The quotes prevent expanding the variable.

Comment: Shouldn't the div id be inside quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the ID, just pass `this`, since the ID points to the same element. Then you don't need to search by ID again.

```js
function hoverOverWindows(div) {
    $(div).addClass('hover-over-windows-style');
};

function hoverAwayFromWindows(div) {
    $(div).removeClass('hover-over-windows-style');
};
```

```css
.home-match-type {
    width: 47%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.home-match-type-left { margin-right: 3% }


.img-text-container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
    background: rgba(60, 122, 173, 0.95);
}

.img-text-container-type-2 { background: rgba(60, 122, 173, 0.95) }

.img-text {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

h3.img-text.img-header { float: left }

h3.img-text.img-header.be-central { float: none }

.img-header {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(213, 213, 213, 0.3);
}

.hover-over-windows-style {
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="assets/css/lib/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<article class="home-match-type home-match-type-left">
            <div class="img-text-container img-text-container-type-2" id="home-m-t-1" onmouseover="hoverOverWindows(this)" onmouseout="hoverAwayFromWindows(this)">
                <h3 class="img-text img-header be-central windows-type-2"><a href="matches/blitz.html">Some Text</a></h3>
                <p class="img-text text-align-centre windows-type-2">lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer </p>
            </div>
        </article>
```

You could also just use the jQuery `.hover()` method:

```
$("#home-m-t-1").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover-over-windows-style');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover-over-windows-style');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a simple one; an incorrect use of quotation marks.

First, you need to wrap your function parameter inside quotes. You're looking for `onmouseover="hoverOverWindows('home-m-t-1')"` instead of 
`onmouseover="hoverOverWindows(home-m-t-1)"`.

Second, you **don't** need quotation marks in the jQuery element target. You're looking for `$(id)` instead of `$('id')` there. You'll also want the removal of the class to target `$(id)` as well, instead of `$('#div')`.

You'll also need to reference jQuery, which wasn't included in your snippet.

I've updated these in the following snippet:

```js
function hoverOverWindows(div) {
  var id = "#" + div;
  $(id).addClass('hover-over-windows-style');
};

function hoverAwayFromWindows(div) {
  var id = "#" + div;
  $(id).removeClass('hover-over-windows-style');
};
```

```css
.home-match-type {
  width: 47%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.home-match-type-left {
  margin-right: 3%
}

.img-text-container {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(60, 122, 173, 0.95);
}

.img-text-container-type-2 {
  background: rgba(60, 122, 173, 0.95)
}

.img-text {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

h3.img-text.img-header {
  float: left
}

h3.img-text.img-header.be-central {
  float: none
}

.img-header {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(213, 213, 213, 0.3);
}

.hover-over-windows-style {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="assets/css/lib/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<article class="home-match-type home-match-type-left">
  <div class="img-text-container img-text-container-type-2" id="home-m-t-1" onmouseover="hoverOverWindows('home-m-t-1')" onmouseout="hoverAwayFromWindows('home-m-t-1')">
    <h3 class="img-text img-header be-central windows-type-2"><a href="matches/blitz.html">Some Text</a></h3>
    <p class="img-text text-align-centre windows-type-2">lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer lorem ipsum sid etc whaetveer </p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Also need to remove the quotes in `$('id')`

Comment: @Barmar -- Yes, good spotting! Didn't initially see that one :)

Comment: And `$('#div")` should also be `$(id)`

Comment: didn't realise it was such a basic error I made. thanks!